# get textbox value inside gridview div tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox inside a div tag which is placed inside a `gridview`.
Below is the code :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color">
    <ItemTemplate>                  

         <div id="preview" style="width:100%; float:right">
             <asp:TextBox ID="TB_color" runat="server" Width="50%" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
         </div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ColorPickerExtender ID="ColorPickerExtender1" runat="server" targetcontrolid="TB_color" samplecontrolid="preview" PopupPosition ="Right" OnClientColorSelectionChanged="colorChanged" />                         
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How to read (or loop through) the TextBox `TB_color` value in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find ids that contains with `TB_color` to find all textboxes as asp.net generate ids that contains `TB_color`

```
for(i=0;i<document.forms[0].length;i++)
{   
    e=document.forms[0].elements[i];
    if (e.id.indexOf("TB_color") != -1 )
    {
       console.log(e.id);
    }
}
```

If you can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) then it will be very simple.

```
$('[id*=TB_color]').each(function(){
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

You may look more about jquery [Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]] or [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: Not Working. How can i iterate through Gridview ?? then i ned to find div , then textbox inside it.

Comment: Try with this condition, if (e.id.indexOf("TB_color") != -1 ), changed the code

Comment: getting this error : `TypeError: document.forms is not a function`

Comment: Take the update code. It assumes you have one form on page of you have multiple then you will have to provide the correct index

Comment: i m able to get the TB id, how to read its text? `e.innerText` is not working.

Comment: For textbox you need value not innerText

Comment: It should work. Do you get some error? the value might be empty string.

Comment: No error, m getting empty as value. But the text box has value.

Comment: You would be assigning value after the script is executed. Try executing it after the textboxes get value. How you assign value to textboxes

Comment: i am executing after TB has values. i am assigning values to Tb from code behind.

Comment: Where you have this script? put is just before end of body tag. <script type="javascript" language="javascript"> code for textbox that I suggested </script> </body>

Answer (score 0):

What are you really trying to accomplish? Maybe iterating through the textfields is not the best option.

You can try setting the [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.100)/html) to `predictable`, that way the ID of your text fields on html will be something like gridId_rowId_preview_TB_color.

If you want to do something to all of the TB_color text fields, you can set some class to the item template, and get all the elements that have that class.